# Margem Branca em mobile - Framework Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

estou  utilizando o twitter bootstrap e ajustes estão okay exceto, uma margem branca que fica a direita do conteúdo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta o código pra poder ser possivel entender o problema.

Comment: Posta o código pra poder ser possivel entender o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo verificar primeiro o seu "esqueleto" do projeto. Já tive problemas semelhantes de um espaçamento maior na parte direita e o acerto foi apenas algumas alterações nos:

```
<div class="col-xx-xx">
```

Se este problema não solucionar, verifique se o seu projeto contém:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Parcialmente também é um dos problemas mais comuns também. Poste seu código para que todos possamos simular o seu problema e tentar solucionar com mais precisão.

Comment: Obrigado,:D revi o código e encontrei e solução :)